# How to keep a component mounted on MacOS

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

My `React Native` (0.61.5) app uses `nodejs-mobile-react-native` (0.40.0, Node 10.17.0). MacOS cataline. Xcode 11.3.

The `ipfs` is installed `global` under `/nodejs-mobile/nodejs-project/` created by `nodejs-mobile-react-native`. There is output when type `jsipfs`. However there is no entry of `ipfs` in the `package.json` under `/nodejs-assets/nodejs-project/`

The process is:
1. the app loads a component `SplashScreen` 
2. 'SplashScreen' calls `main.js` (via `nodejs-mobile-react-native`)

Here is the `main.js`:

```
var rn_bridge = require('rn-bridge');
const IPFS = require('ipfs');  //<<<=== this line causes the page unmounted

async function init() {
  const node = await IPFS.create()
  console.log("rn bridge inited!", node.version);
};

init();

// Echo every message received from react-native.
rn_bridge.channel.on('message', (msg) => {
  rn_bridge.channel.send(msg);
  console.log("Message from RN : ", msg);
} );

// Inform react-native node is initialized.
rn_bridge.channel.send("Node was initialized.");
```

Here is the component `SplashScreen`:

```js
import nodejs from 'nodejs-mobile-react-native';

class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  state = {};

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("Unmount splash screen");
    this._isMounted = false;
    nodejs.channel.removeListener("messange");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    console.log("Nodejs obj : ", nodejs);
    nodejs.start("main.js");
    nodejs.channel.addListener(
      "message",
      (msg) => {
        alert("From node: " + msg);
        console.log("Message from nodejs : ", msg);
      },
      this
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button title="Message Node 1"
          //onPress={() => nodejs.channel.send('A message1!')}
          onPress={() => alert('A message1!')}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

Here the `main.js` is executed in `SplashScreen` constructor. The problem is that the `SplashScreen` only loads for a fraction of second

[image]

Then the following is loaded and stays:

[image]

How to make component `SplashScreen` stay mounted?

Comment: nodejs-mobile-react-native is functioning before ipfs installed.

Comment: Why is your question entitled “macOS” and you use android screenshots?

Comment: Because he's probably using MacOS to build his react-native app before deploying it to the android device.